# How to create class using object literal notation in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I want to create a class in Java Script. I can use basic functions coupled with prototypes but I want to use Object Literal Notation. Is is possible to create classes using Object Literal Notations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot create an instance of an object (and yes, you could even see functions as objects in Javascript, but I'm talking about literal defined objects), you must use a function to define a reusable class.

Answer (score 0):

Cannot be done....well, depends on how you define the params of the requirements.  Should be done? Up for debate.

The following is from an idea a coworker of mine had.

http://bit.ly/18xGdKi [JSBin with console example]

```
if (typeof (makeClass) === "undefined") {
  makeClass = function(o) {
    var F = function () {};

    if (typeof (o) === "object" && o !== null) {
      if (typeof (o.constructor) === "function") {
        F = o.constructor;
      }

      F.prototype = o;
    }

    return F;
  };
}

var MyClass = makeClass({
  constructor: function (pName) {
    var _myPrivateIdaho = 'Idaho ' + pName;
    this.name = pName;

    var _myPrivateFunc = function() {
      console.log('You are in my ' + 
                  _myPrivateIdaho +'.');
    };

    _myPrivateFunc();
  },
  getName: function() {
    return this.name;
  }
});

new MyClass('Bob');
new MyClass('Steve');
```